How many sunnah prayer rakat are there related to dhuhr prayer?
Sunnah fajr= 4 rakat. 2 rakat fard+ 2 rakat sunnah.
Sunnah Zuhr= 10 rakat. 4 rakat sunnah and fard+ 2 final sunnah.
Sunnah Asr= 8 rakat. 4 rakat sunnah and fard.
Sunnah Maghirb= 5 rakat. 3 rakat fard+ 2 rakat sunnah.
Sunnah Isha= 10 rakat. 4 rakat sunnah and fard+ 2 final sunnah.
This is what I have done.
But when I go on deeper research this is the correct sunnah.


Narrated Umm Habibah:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If anyone keeps on praying regularly four rak'ahs before and four after the noon prayer, he will not enter the Hell-fire.
Abu Dawud said: Al-'Ala' bin Al-Harith and Sulaiman bin Musa reported it from Makhul with his chain, similarly. (Sunan abi Dawud)

So does it mean I need to do...
4 rakat sunnah,  4 rakat fard and 4 rakat sunnah
3 times 4 rakat
Altogether is 12 rakat zuhr, but 8 rakat sunnah rakat.
Moreover I have heard when someone pray 12 rakat Allah will give house in Jannah, so does it mean I need to pray exactly 12 rakat sunnah or it can be more 12 rakat.
So my point on zuhr should i do 4 rakat sunnah+ 4 rakat fard+ 4 rakat sunnah or 2 rakat.
I want to clear the misconception about sunnah rakat.

Your question was already asked Sunnah prayer how many raka'a? and simply speaking to answer it we need to agree on a definition what is sunnah prayer and how it is different than nafl? Further, one must take into account that different madhhabs defined different amounts of sunnah/nafl prayers and raka'a.

@Medi1Saif But it doesn't mention house in jannah or make hellfire prohibited.

I've removed the tags because they are irrelevant for answering the question itself. If you think otherwise the question is yours.

@Medi1Saif Ok, so can you please answer my question?

@Medi1Saif, What do you mean by term?

@Medi1Saif But I have heard if someone pray 12 rakat sunnah Allah provide house in Jannah, and if anyone keeps on praying regularly four rak'ahs before and four after the noon prayer, he will not enter the Hell-fire.
So does it mean I need to do...
4 rakat sunnah, 4 rakat fard and 4 rakat sunnah
3 times 4 rakat.
Altogether is 12 rakat zuhr, but 8 rakat sunnah rakat.

I've added the tag [tag:hadith-interpretation] this way at least this question should be answerable. Do you have a line for the hadith in question? I strongly recommend you to keep the question focussed on dhuhr prayer! So please edit it yourself.

@Medi1Saif Ok thank.
